# How to find max value and the associated field in sql?

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the highest ID and its description from a table using the following code. However it keeps returning null. Please could someone suggest where i am going wrong

```
Select  ID, Description
FROM STOPS
where Description = (select MAX(ID) 
from STOPS);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `where ID = (select MAX(ID) ...`

Answer (score 3):

Use `order by` and the equivalent of `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select s.*
from stops s
order by s.id desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is ANSI-standard syntax.  Not all databases support `fetch first`, some use `limit`, `select top`, or `rownum`.